# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader::getIdValue() must be an object or null, string given

Tags: php, symfony

BlogType

```
        ->add('category',EntityType::class,[
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => function(Category $category) {
                return $category->getName();
            }
        ])
```

Category Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit-post/{id}", name="edit-post")
 */
public function editBlogPost(ManagerRegistry $manager, $id){
    $post = $manager->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    dd($post);
}
```

Error:

> Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader::getIdValue() must be
> an object or null, string given

When I do dd in $post I get above error, Is there any soln to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you've implemented __toString() in the entity obj you don't need to define the choice_label in the BlogType.

But if you delete `__toString()` (and you should so you let Symfony deal with the form) you can simply write `'choice_label' => 'name'`

Comment: Hello @Giuseppe I did `'choice_label' => 'name'` but still getting same error